# inheritance in python : not getting expected o/p

Tags: python

```
class Employee:

    raise_amount = 1.02

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first+'.'+last+'@company.com'

    def fullname(self):
        return f"Full name is {self.first} {self.last}"

    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * Employee.raise_amount)


class Developer(Employee):
    raise_amount = 1.10

dev1 = Developer('Test1','User1',20000)
dev2 = Developer('Test2','User2',25000)   

print(dev1.pay)
dev1.apply_raise()
print(dev1.pay)
```

O/p : 
20000
20400

where as the o/p should have been 
20000
22000

22000, Because we are overriding the class variable in the subclass

what is that which im doing wrong here

Comment: Change `Employee.raise_amount` to `self.raise_amount` and think about it

Answer (score 2):

You should change

```
self.pay = int(self.pay * Employee.raise_amount)
```

to

```
self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amount)
```

that way, the lookup of the class variable is done the way you expect it.

It will all be less confusing if you use a instance variable instead of a class variable to achieve what you want.

Comment: It's still a class variable

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes. That's why I wrote "that way the lookup of the **class variable** is done the way you expect it." I only mentiond in a side note, that using an instance variable from the start might lead to a less surprising behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You create a subclass but the parent uses `Employee.raise_amount` for calculations, hard coding the class. Change that to `self.raise_amount` so that the parent method will use the subclass variable instead.

```
    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

def apply_raise(self):
    self.pay = int(self.pay * Employee.raise_amount)

try replacing Employee with self

def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amount)